# Width of character

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character, string-length

I have a problem with unicode characters, they are wider or narrower than an  usual character.

Code:

```
for base in bases:
    print("'{}'   ".format(base), end=''), time.sleep(1)
print()
for bit in bits:
    print("'{}'   ".format(bit), end=''), time.sleep(1)
print()
```

Output:

> '+'   '+'   '×'   '×'   '+'   '×'   '×'   '+'   '×'   '×'   '×'   '×'   '+'   '×'   '+'   '+'   '×'   '×'   '×'   '+'
>   '→'   '↑'   '↗'   '↗'   '↑'   '↗'   '↖'   '→'   '↖'   '↗'   '↗'   '↗'   '→'   '↗'   '→'   '→'   '↖'   '↗'   '↖'   '→'

I would like to first and second line in output are in a same 'length'. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks, I changed a font in PyCharm from 'monospaced' to 'source code pro' and it works.

Comment: To clarify, apparently what happened was that the default font didn't contain these characters, so the renderer chose another font to display them, which was not a monospaced font. Specifying a font that does contain these characters solves the issue.